# How to unit test accepts_nested_attributes_for with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I have an `Invoice` with various `Items`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :date, :recipient, :items_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

However, I am struggling with an RSpec unit test for that model. For example, I would like to test that an invoice will throw an error if it has no item.

This doesn't work:

```
describe Invoice do

  it "is invalid without an item" do
    expect(build(:invoice, :items_attributes => {}).to have(1).errors_on(:items_attributes)
  end

end
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

From the accepts_nested_attributes_for [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
You may also set a :reject_if proc to silently ignore any new record hashes if they fail to pass your criteria.
```

Documentation doesn't specify what they mean by **silently** but it might be without throwing an exception....

Try to set up some validation, presence, on Item model attributes that will definitely throw some exceptions end should be loud enough for rspec expect{..}.to block to work.